# i need to be on the line to create data using sql that stores articles

Tags: c#, sql

i need to be on the line to create database using sql that stores articles  .. like news.. in other words the data base should have image and title of the article and autonumber id for the article and its category id and the text .. my website design is ready and im using visual studio 2010 c# .. i need each article have link and when i press it view it with its image and  its body text and its title .... sorry for my language .. if any one can help me with hints or links it'll be great ..

Comment: You'll need to ask specific questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Regarding your question.
How is that you have your website ready without having any idea of how to handle the data and save it in the Database?

You have done a very generic question, without giving any information of how you have solved your issues so far, or what technologies you are using.

There is tons of ways of doing what you want.
I would suggest that you use either [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

Then maybe look samples on how to implement CRUD with them.